# Common handler for DBGrid and DBGridEh's columns visibility

Tags: delphi

Which class does `TDBGridEh` belong to? I tried:

```
if (AForm.Components[i] IS TDBGridEh)
if (AForm.Components[i] IS TCustomDBGrid) or 
if (AForm.Components[i] IS TCustomGrid) or
if (AForm.Components[i] IS TDBGrid) or
```

but I get error: undeclared identifier '***'

**UPDATE:**

This is my common handler for subelements of `TMainMenu`, and for columns of `TDBGrid`. I have to add in this common handler some code for `TDBGridEh`.

Is there a way to have one procedure for subelements of `TDBGrid`, `TDBGridEh`, and `TMainMenu`?

```pascal
procedure RightsOnSubElements(AForm: TForm; AComp: TComponent);

  function FindFieldColumn(AComp: TComponent; const FieldName: String):  TColumn;
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    Result := nil;
    for i := 0 to (AComp as TDBGrid).Columns.Count - 1 do
      if AnsiCompareText((AComp as TDBGrid).Columns[i].FieldName, FieldName) = 0 then
      begin
        Result := (AComp as TDBGrid).Columns[i];
        Break;
      end;
  end;
     
var
  Column : TColumn;
  i: Integer;
begin
  fMain.qSubElements.Close;
  fMain.qSubElements.Parambyname('Form_Name').AsString := AForm.Name;
  fMain.qSubElements.Parambyname('ROLE_ID').AsInteger := ROLE_ID;
  fMain.qSubElements.Parambyname('name').AsString := AComp.Name;
  fMain.qSubElements.Open;
  if fMain.qSubElements.RecordCount > 0 then begin
    while not fMain.qSubElements.Eof do begin
      for i := 0 to AForm.ComponentCount - 1 do
        if (AForm.Components[i] is TMenuItem) then begin
          if UpperCase(AForm.Components[i].Name) = UpperCase(fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Sub_Name').AsString) then
          begin
            (AForm.Components[i] as TMenuItem).Visible := fmain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Visible').AsBoolean;
            (AForm.Components[i] as TMenuItem).Enabled := fmain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Enabled').AsBoolean;
          end;
        end
        else if (AForm.Components[i] is TDBGrid) then begin
          if UpperCase(AForm.Components[i].Name) = UpperCase(fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Name').AsString) then
          begin
            Column := FindFieldColumn(AComp as TDBGrid, fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('sub_name').AsString);
            if Assigned(Column) then Column.Visible := fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Visible').AsBoolean;
          end;
      end;
                
      fMain.qSubElements.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You do know that you can use [ClassParent](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TObject.ClassParent) method to find parent class of every existing class in your application. Put this into loop and you can get a whole hierarchy tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is parent class of DBGridEh component?

According to EhLib's [documentation](http://www.ehlib.com/online-help/):

- [`TDBGridEh`](http://www.ehlib.com/online-help/DBGridEh_TDBGridEh.html) derives from [`TCustomDBGridEh`](http://www.ehlib.com/online-help/DBGridEh_TCustomDBGridEh.html),
- which derives from [`TCustomDBAxisGridEh`](http://www.ehlib.com/online-help/DBAxisGridsEh_TCustomDBAxisGridEh.html),
- which derives from [`TCustomGridEh`](http://www.ehlib.com/online-help/GridsEh_TCustomGridEh.html),
- which derives from [`TCustomControl`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TCustomControl)

So, when `AForm.Components[i]` refers to a `TDBGridEh` object, it will test positive for `TDBGridEh`, but will test negative for `TCustomDBGrid`, `TCustomGrid`, and `TDBGrid`.

You already know how to differentiate `TMainMenu` from `TDBGrid`, so what is stopping you from differentiating `TDBGridEh` from `TDBGrid`?

```pascal
procedure RightsOnSubElements(AForm: TForm; AComp: TComponent);

  function FindFieldColumn(AComp: TDBGrid; const FieldName: String): TColumn;
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to AComp.Columns.Count - 1 do begin
      Result := AComp.Columns[i];
      if SameText(Reslut.FieldName, FieldName) then
        Exit;
    end;
    Result := nil;
  end;
     
  function FindFieldColumnEh(AComp: TDBGridEh; const FieldName: String): TColumnEh;
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to AComp.Columns.Count - 1 do begin
      Result := AComp.Columns[i];
      if SameText(Result.FieldName, FieldName) then
        Exit;
    end;
    Result := nil;
  end;

var
  Comp: TComponent;
  Column : TColumn;
  ColumnEh : TColumnEh;
  i: Integer;
begin
  fMain.qSubElements.Close;
  fMain.qSubElements.Parambyname('Form_Name').AsString := AForm.Name;
  fMain.qSubElements.Parambyname('ROLE_ID').AsInteger := ROLE_ID;
  fMain.qSubElements.Parambyname('name').AsString := AComp.Name;
  fMain.qSubElements.Open;
  while not fMain.qSubElements.Eof do begin
    Comp := AForm.FindComponent(fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Name').AsString);
    if (Comp is TMenuItem) then begin
      with TMenuItem(Comp) do begin
        Visible := fmain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Visible').AsBoolean;
        Enabled := fmain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Enabled').AsBoolean;
      end;
    end
    else if (Comp is TDBGrid) then begin
      Column := FindFieldColumn(TDBGrid(Comp), fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Sub_Name').AsString);
      if Column <> nil then Column.Visible := fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Visible').AsBoolean;
    end
    else if (Comp is TDBGridEh) then begin
      ColumnEh := FindFieldColumnEh(TDBGridEh(Comp), fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Sub_Name').AsString);
      if Column <> nil then Column.Visible := fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Visible').AsBoolean;
    end;                
    fMain.qSubElements.Next;
  end;
end;
```

---

That being said, since `TDBGridEh` has similar interfaces to, but is not actually derived from, `TDBGrid`, then in Delphi 2009+ you could write common code for both `TDBGrid` and `TDBGridEh` by using [Generics](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Generics_Index), eg:

```pascal
type
  TInternalDBGridHelper<TDBGridType: class, TColumnType: class> = class 
    class function FindFieldColumn(AGrid: TDBGridType; const AFieldName: string): TColumnType;
    class procedure SetFieldColumnVisible(AGrid: TDBGridType; const AFieldName: string; AVisible: Boolean);
  end;

  TInternalHelper_DBGrid   = TInternalDBGridHelper<TDBGrid, TColumn>;
  TInternalHelper_DBGridEh = TInternalDBGridHelper<TDBGridEh, TColumnEh>;

  TDBGridHelper = class helper for TDBGrid
    procedure SetFieldColumnVisible(const AFieldName: string; AVisible: Boolean);
  end;

  TDBGridEhHelper = class helper for TDBGridEh
    procedure SetFieldColumnVisible(const AFieldName: string; AVisible: Boolean);
  end;

class function TInternalDBGridHelper<TDBGridType, TColumnType>.FindFieldColumn(
  AGrid: TDBGridType; const AFieldName: string): TColumnType;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to AGrid.Columns.Count-1 do
  begin
    Result := AGrid.Columns[I];
    if SameText(Result.FieldName, AFieldName) then
      Exit;
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;

class function TInternalDBGridHelper<TDBGridType, TColumnType>.SetFieldColumnVisible(
  AGrid: TDBGridType; const AFieldName: string; AVisible: Boolean);
var
  Column: TColumnType;
begin
  Column := FindFieldColumn(AGrid, AFieldName);
  if Assigned(Column) then Column.Visible := AVisible;
end;

procedure TDBGridHelper.SetFieldColumnVisible(const AFieldName: string; AVisible: Boolean);
begin
  TInternalHelper_DBGrid.SetFieldColumnVisible(Self, AFieldName, AVisible);
end;

procedure TDBGridEhHelper.SetFieldColumnVisible(const AFieldName: string; AVisible: Boolean);
begin
  TInternalHelper_DBGridEh.SetFieldColumnVisible(Self, AFieldName, AVisible);
end;

procedure RightsOnSubElements(AForm: TForm; AComp: TComponent);
var
  Comp: TComponent;
  i: Integer;
begin
  fMain.qSubElements.Close;
  fMain.qSubElements.Parambyname('Form_Name').AsString := AForm.Name;
  fMain.qSubElements.Parambyname('ROLE_ID').AsInteger := ROLE_ID;
  fMain.qSubElements.Parambyname('name').AsString := AComp.Name;
  fMain.qSubElements.Open;
  while not fMain.qSubElements.Eof do begin
    Comp := AForm.FindComponent(fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Name').AsString);
    if (Comp is TMenuItem) then begin
      with TMenuItem(Comp) do begin
        Visible := fmain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Visible').AsBoolean;
        Enabled := fmain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Enabled').AsBoolean;
      end;
    end
    else if (Comp is TDBGrid) then begin
      TDBGrid(Comp).SetFieldColumnVisible(
        fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Sub_Name').AsString,
        fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Visible').AsBoolean);
    end
    else if (Comp is TDBGridEh) then begin
      TDBGridEh(Comp).SetFieldColumnVisible(
        fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Sub_Name').AsString,
        fMain.qSubElements.FieldByName('Visible').AsBoolean);
    end;                
    fMain.qSubElements.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Remy Lebeau, As I see there is no way to have one common procedure for set visibility of columns of DBGrid, columns of DBGridEh and items of MainMenu. 
Thank you for you code example.

Comment: Remy Lebeau ,how you call you procedure? For example I call my procedure so: RightsOnSubElements(self, MainMenu1) or RightsOnSubElements(self, dbgrid1) and you? 
p.s. I add full procedure above. 
thank you.

Comment: "*As I see there is no way to have one common procedure for*" - Not when they have different types, no. But, if they have common names, you could always resort to RTTI. There are, of course, other design idioms you can use instead (polymorphic wrappers, etc). "*how you call you procedure?*" - I don't understand what you are asking. The example I posted shows you how they are called. What is stopping you from applying my example code to your situation? I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Remy Lebeau  I'll try tomorrow and inform about result. thank you very much for you attempts.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, compile errors are displayed: 'undeclared identifier TColumnType', 'TColumnType is not a type identifier', 'Undeclared identifier: 'TInternalDBGridHelper'.  :(

Comment: @basti what version of Delphi are you using? I don't have a working compiler installed at the moment, I'm writing this code from memory, so I can't guarantee I got the syntax 100% correct, but I think I did.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, you code's previous version (without class functions) works fine. You change it before I see. :)  Thank you.